Airflow FileSensor, find new file in folder
I have the problem:
Files that have a common mask constantly fall into one folder, on different dates in the names.
For example:
One file is called my_file_2024-10-22_10_35, and the second my_file_2024-10-22_18_35....
That is, they have the date type yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm, and files with a common mask my_file_* will appear in the specified folder, but with different dates of appearance.
I used the FileSensor class, but it monitors exactly the change of a specific file in a folder.
What should I do if I need, as soon as the same file appears, a file with a suitable mask so that Airflow starts the task immediately via FileSensor().
The example of code:
start_sensor = FileSensor(
    task_id='start_sensor', 
    filepath= '/path_to_file/my_file_*',
    poke_interval=10, 
    timeout=300, 
    soft_fail = False
    )
@task
def copy_file():
    files = os.listdir('path_to_file')
    matching_files = [
        f for f in files if re.match(r"_my_file*", f)
    ]
    print("Files in folder:", matching_files)
    latest_file = max(
        matching_files, key=lambda f: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path_to_file, f)
...

def run()
    start_sensor >> copy_file()

run()

I tried to do two tasks:

To make a sensor that will find the appearance of a specific file by mask.
If the trigger found the appearance, then run task copy_file, which finds the newest file in the folder.

